# Different Wav Files not working with OpenAL / PyAl

Tags: python, wav, openal

I found the following code on [github](https://github.com/ctk0418/pyal/tree/master/examples) that uses PyAL to create sounds that appear to move towards you by using the OpenAL library.

I downloaded all the files and went into the example folders to run the following audioplayer.py. It worked perfectly fine with the hey.wav file.

Now I wanted to run the exact same thing but with a different sound. So I got the following [wav file](https://www.pacdv.com/sounds/voices/no-1.wav) and ran audioplayer.py. But the sound does not appear to be moving towards me and then away as it did for the hey.wav file. It just makes a constant sound over and over again.

I am confused why it works for one wav file and not for another?

```
"""OpenAL playback example."""
import os
import sys
import time
from openal.audio import SoundSink, SoundSource
from openal.loaders import load_wav_file

def run():
    if len (sys.argv) < 2:
        print ("Usage: %s wavefile" % os.path.basename(sys.argv[0]))
        print ("    Using an example wav file...")
        dirname = os.path.dirname(__file__)
        fname = os.path.join(dirname, "hey.wav")
    else:
        fname = sys.argv[1]


    sink = SoundSink()
    sink.activate()

    source = SoundSource(position=[10, 0, 0])
    source.looping = True

    data = load_wav_file(fname)
    source.queue(data)

    sink.play(source)
    while source.position[0] > - 10:
        source.position = [source.position[0] - 1,
                           source.position[1],
                           source.position[2]]
        sink.update()
        print("playing at %r" % source.position)
        time.sleep(2)
    print("done")


if __name__ == "__main__":
    sys.exit(run())
```

Comment: There is some documentation here https://pythonhosted.org/PyAL/audio.html but I still don't know what could be the issue

Answer (score 2):

The audio file needs to be mono and not stereo